# Passagem de variaveis de uma função para outra em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Estou com dificuldades em passar as variáveis n e m da função partida para a função `computador_escolhe_jogada`. A própria mensagem de erro aponta:

> TypeError: computador_escolhe_jogada() missing 2 required positional
>   arguments: 'n' and 'm'

Como posso passar os valores? desde já agradeço.

```py
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m):
    if n == m+1:
        return "você começa"
        usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
    else:
        return "Computador começa!"
    while n != 0 :
        return ("O Computador tirou" , (m+1))
        return ("Agora restam",(m+1)-(n), "no tabuleiro")
        usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)

def partida():
    n = int(input("Quantas peças? "))
    m = int(input("Limite de peças por jogada? "))
    computador_escolhe_jogada()
```

Comment: João, evite utilizar mais de um retorno por função.
Sugiro que pesquise pela função __init__():
Ela serve para iniciar variáveis em comum para múltiplas funções em uma classe.

Comment: @WillianJesusDaSilva O problema do rapaz acima são apenas métodos, ele não esta utilizando classes e a função __init__ é apenas para a inicialização das classes, mas sim, concordo que o segundo return dele não esta servindo de nada e caso que queira compartilhar a saída, pode retorna ambos em uma lista ou criar uma função generator com o uso de yield

Answer (score 1):

Ao chamar a função `computador_escolhe_jogada` você precisa informar os paramentos que irá passar, desta forma `computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m)`

```
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m):
if n == m+1:
    return "você começa"
    usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
else:
    return "Computador começa!"
while n != 0 :
    return ("O Computador tirou" , (m+1))
    return ("Agora restam",(m+1)-(n), "no tabuleiro")
    usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)

def partida():
n = int(input("Quantas peças? "))
m = int(input("Limite de peças por jogada? "))
computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
```